# Sorting linked list while inserting a node

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, linked-list

I am trying to create sorted linked list = sorting it while creating it. Idea is simple , insert a node - and check if previous is smaller , if so check previous of previous and so on until it finds its spot. I have created this piece of code.

```
struct Node{
    Node *prev;
    Node *next;
    int value;
};

struct List{
    Node *head = nullptr;
    Node *tail = nullptr;
};
```

Here i created a node , and a "holder" for the list = reference to first and last item of the list.

```
void insertNode(Node *&head,Node *&tail, int value ){
    Node *tmp = new Node;
    tmp -> prev = nullptr;
    tmp -> next = nullptr;
    tmp -> value = value;
    head = tmp;
    tail = tmp;
}
```

this function checks if list is empty , if yes , it inserts node to head and tail ( e.g head = tail  = there is only one node in list );

What troubles me is function to insert a node

```
void insertIt(Node *&head , Node *&tail , int value){
    if( head == nullptr){
        insertNode(head,tail,value);
    }
    else{
        Node *tmp = new Node;
        tmp -> value = value;

        if( value < tail -> value){    
            while(value < tail -> prev -> value){                
                tail = tail -> prev;
                if( tail -> prev == nullptr){                    
                    tmp -> next = head;
                    tmp -> prev = nullptr;
                    head -> prev = tmp;
                    head = tmp;
                    return;
                }
            }
            tail -> prev -> next = tmp;
            tmp -> prev =  tail -> prev;
            tmp -> next = tail;
            tail -> prev = tmp;
        }else{    
            tmp -> next = nullptr;
            tmp ->prev = tail;
            tail -> next = tmp;
            tail = tmp;
        }
    }
}
```

If list is empty , it invokes `insertNode()` , if value of the node is smaller than value of previous node , it crawls the list to find its spot.

This piece code works only if the first node inserted is also a smallest node there will be. e.g

```
insertIt(list.head , list.tail , -1);
insertIt(list.head , list.tail , 0);
insertIt(list.head , list.tail , 7);
insertIt(list.head , list.tail , 1);
insertIt(list.head , list.tail , 2);
insertIt(list head , list.tail , 2);
```

works and if i print the list it is nice sorted. but

```
insertIt(list.head , list.tail , -2);
insertIt(list.head , list.tail , -1);
insertIt(list.head , list.tail , 7);
insertIt(list.head , list.tail , 1);
insertIt(list.head , list.tail , 2);
insertIt(list.head , list.tail , 2);
```

the first node isnt the smallest node , it crashes the program. I thought it was i was comparing a value to nullptr so i added the piece of code which you can see in `insertIt()` function and that is

```
if( tail -> prev == nullptr){
    tmp -> next = head;
    tmp -> prev = nullptr;
    head -> prev = tmp;
    head = tmp;
    return;
}
```

This checks if the node is a head , and swap head with new node , making new node new head.

Why does it crashes code? I failed to find a reasonable answer to this. Also , how could I improve my "algorithm" to make it more effective?

Comment: First of all you should run in a debugger to catch the crash in action and see where it is and what the values of all involved variables are. If it doesn't help then use the debugger to step through the code, line by line, to see what it does and how all the variables change.

Comment: "If list is empty , it invokes insertNode() , if value of the node is smaller than value of previous node.." ?? But the list is empty..

Comment: I am using code blocks , and debugger pointed, at the line of code i added  ( the last code i wrote) , i am kinda new to c/c++ world , havent used a debugger that much , i guess code blocks debugger isnt the best one. Could you recommend some good one?

Comment: What I can see is that in `insertIt`, you reset `tail` while looking for the correct spot to insert the new node, thus destroying the pointer to the last node in the linked list. The correct way would be using another pointer that you initialize to the tail and use that instead for searching. Anyway, you dereference `tail->prev` using `tail->prev->value` without checking that `tail->prev != nullptr`.

Comment: When you post code, try and make sure your indentation is consistent and readable, and that you don't have an excess of whitespace. Also note: C != C++ and "c/c++" is a poor shorthand for C and/or C++, especially when one means only one of them.

Comment: Did i tag also a  C? Didnt notice , sorry for that.

Comment: @trolkura someone else added the C tag (which I have recently removed), but you do say "c/c++" in a comment above. :)

Comment: When inserting into a doubly-linked list you have three normal cases: prepending at the beginning, appending at the end and inserting somewhere inside the list, which correspond to not having the previous item, not having the next item and having both prev and next one; and a special case of inserting to an empty list, when there is no prev and no next item. Are you sure your considered all four cases when designing your code?

Comment: Please see the edited answer.

Answer (score 2):

You want to do two things: find position in list where new node belongs AND insert new node at a position.  So, write two functions, one to do each task.  Then you can test and debug them separately before integrating.  This will be much more straight forward. Further reccomendation: write unit tests for each function, before implementing the functions.

```
/** Find node with largest value less than given 
    Assumes sorted list exist.  If empty, throws exception
*/
Node & FindLessThan( int value );

/** Inset new node after given with value */
InsertAfter( Node& n, int value );
```

It will also be handy to have a function to  insert the first node, if the list is empty,

```
/** Insert first node with value
    @return true if list empty */
bool InsertFirstNode( int value );
```

The point is that you should hide all the pointer twiddling in functions that can be tested, so you can write a comprehensible mainline that will work first time:

```
if( ! InsertFirstNode( value ) )
   InsertAfter( FindLessThan( value ), value );
```

Since you are using C++, make your list a class and the functions members.

Implementation details:  You have to worry about special cases: new value goes before head or after tail.  So I suggest using an enumeration to handle these.

```
/** Special cases for placing a new node */
enum class eFind
{
    list_empty,         // the list was empty
    before_first,       // the new node goes before the first node in list
    before_node,        // the new node goes before the specified node
    after_last,         // the new node goes after the last node in the list
}; 
/** Find node with smallest value greater than given

    @param[out] place eFind enumeration, one of list_empty,before_first,before_node,after_last
    @param[in] value being inserted

    @return n node before which value should be placed

    Assumes sorted list exist.
*/
Node * FindSmallestGreaterThan( eFind & place, int value )
```

It also turns out to be slightly easier ( less code ) to do an InsertBefore rather than InsertAfter.  You can see the code running at [cpp.sh/4xitp](http://cpp.sh/4xitp) or the [github gist](https://gist.github.com/JamesBremner/f26a7f4ce96e36a5d8f7)

Comment: Thanks for advice , i will try to recreate it using separated functions.

Comment: What reference should `Node & FindLessThan( int value )` return if a new value is less than all those already in a list?

Comment: The enumeration value 'before_first'.  Have you looked at the running code at cpp.sh/4xitp

Answer (score 2):

When iterating over the list to find the position to insert a new node, you do:

```
  tail = tail -> prev;
```

But the `tail` variable is passed by a *reference*, that is you modify the `tail` member of yout `List` object, thus destroying its consistency.

Use another temporary variable, named, say `current` or `position` to walk along the list, and don't modify `tail` unless you're appending a new node at the end of the list.

**EDIT** example approach

```
struct Node {
    Node(int val);

    Node *prev;
    Node *next;
    int value;
};

struct List{
    List() : head(nullptr), tail(nullptr) {}
    void insert(int value);

    Node *head;
    Node *tail;
};

Node::Node(int val) :
    value(val), next(nullptr), prev(nullptr)
{
}

void List::insert(int value) {
    Node *tmp = new Node(value);

    if(head == nullptr) {
        head = tmp;
        tail = tmp;
        return;
    }

    Node *pos;  // find the node greater or equal to 'value'
    for(pos = head; pos && pos->value < value; pos = pos->next)
        ;

    if(pos) {    // appropriate pos found - insert before
        tmp->next = pos;
        tmp->prev = pos->prev;
        tmp->next->prev = tmp;
        if(tmp->prev)       // there is some predecessor
            tmp->prev->next = tmp;
        else
            head = tmp;     // making a new first node
    } else {     // pos not found - append at the end
        tmp->next = nullptr;
        tmp->prev = tail;
        tail->next = tmp;
        tail = tmp;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**1.** You can't initialize members inside a structure :

```
struct List
{
    Node *head;
    Node *tail;
};
```

**2.(a)** Prototypes of functions `insertIt` and `insertNode` are wrong.You are passing `head` and `tail` using pass by reference.It should be  as follows :

`void insertIt(Node * head ,Node * tail ,int value)`

`void insertNode(Node * head,Node * tail,int value)`

**2.(b)** When you create a node in `else` part you should set the `next` and `prev` pointers of your new node to `NULL` :

```
tmp->prev=NULL;
tmp->next=NULL;
```

**2.(c)** As you have passed `tail` using pass by reference whatever changes you make inside while loop on `tail` are reflected in program.Hence use temporary pointer of type `Node`.

**3.** Also the design you are using is not good.Hence I would advice you to change it.This is my implementation of linked list :

```
main()
{
    struct List Q;
    Initialize_list(&Q);
    Insert_it(&Q,12);
}
void Initialize_list(struct List *L)
{
    L->head=NULL;
    L->tail=NULL;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the check `value < tail->prev->value` in the `while` loop head. This does not check that `tail->prev != nullptr` is true. This is a problem for the case that `head == tail` and `value < head->value`. If `head != tail`, your code would indeed work, because the first time `value < tail->prev->value` is evaluated, `tail->prev != nullptr` is true and the case `head->next == tail` would be caught by the code in the loop body.
The correct check would be `tail->prev != nullptr && value < tail->prev->value`. This first checks that `tail->prev` can be derefenced.

Then you may end with `tail->prev == nullptr` after finishing the `while` loop (due to the new condition). The check for that can be moved out of the loop, leading to the following code:

```
while (tail->prev != nullptr && value < tail->prev->value) {
    tail = tail->prev;
}
if (tail->prev == nullptr) {
    // Prepend node to the list
    return;
}
// Insert node in front of tail
```

**EDIT**: You can still check the condition `tail->prev == nullptr` within the loop; the check after the loop would then only be useful to catch the case `head == tail && value < head->value`. Not doing the check in the loop has the benefit of a shorter and (in my opinion) mode readable code.

Answer (score 0):

This might be the code you're looking for ;-) You can run it as-is in VS2013. It simplifies your insert function to just a few if-statements. And that can be further simplified with use of terminal elements for head & tail.

I hope this helps :-)

```
struct Node
{
    int value; Node *prev, *next;
};

struct DoublyLinkedSortedList
{
    Node *head = nullptr, *tail = nullptr;

    void insert(int value)
    {
        // Find first node bigger then the new element, or get to the end of the list
        Node* node = head;
        while (node && node->value <= value) { node = node->next; }

        // Once found, insert your new element before the currently pointed node, or at the end of the list
        node = new Node{ value, node?node->prev:tail, node };
        if (node->prev) node->prev->next = node; else head = node;
        if (node->next) node->next->prev = node; else tail = node;
    }
};

#include <climits>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "This is a DoublyLinkedList test." << endl << endl;

    // test the list
    DoublyLinkedSortedList list;
    list.insert(234);
    list.insert(INT_MIN);
    list.insert(17);
    list.insert(1);
    list.insert(INT_MAX);
    list.insert(-34);
    list.insert(3);
    list.insert(INT_MAX);
    list.insert(INT_MIN);
    list.insert(9);
    list.insert(7);

    // print nodes in order;
    cout << "This are the contents of the linked list front to back" << endl << endl;
    for (Node* curr = list.head; curr != nullptr; curr = curr->next) { cout << curr->value << "; "; }
    cout << endl << endl << "This are the contents of the linked list back to front" << endl << endl;
    for (Node* curr = list.tail; curr != nullptr; curr = curr->prev) { cout << curr->value << "; "; }
    cout << endl << endl;

    system("pause");
}
```